# Finding quantiles of a non-linear mapping of a bivariate gaussian

Tags: statistics

Let $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ be a bivariate Gaussian, and let $Y = f(X)$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continous mapping.

I want to compute the quantiles $0.15, 0.5, 085$ of $Y$, and I have a function to compute $f$ on sample points.

For this I generated a mesh of 2D points around $\mu$, and computed both $f$ and the density on those points. Then I sorted the points by their image $f(x)$ and summed the density until the sum divided by the total sum of the density equals the desired quantile.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: I think it is better to do the following: sample many independent samples $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ from $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and sort $f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_n)$. This approximates the true distribution of $Y$; the quantile of $f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_n)$ (e.g., $0.5$ quantile is the median of these $n$ numbers) will approximate the quantile of $Y$.

Comment: @angryavian that sounds quite reasonable too - do you have any heuristics on why it might be better to do that and what sample size I should be using?

Comment: It can be shown that the asymptotic variance of the $q'th$ sample quantile is 
$\frac{q(1-q)}{n f_Y(\nu)^2}$, where $f_Y(\nu)$ is the density of $Y$ at the actual $q'th$ quantile. So if you want standard deviation less than say $\epsilon$, then you shold pick $n \geq \frac{q(1-q)}{\epsilon^2 f_Y(\nu)^2}$ samples. Unfortunately $f_Y(\nu)$ is unknown, but maybe you can give a lower bound? (or just take as many samples your computer can compute in reasonable time)

Comment: The summing of densities could work for discrete random variables, but i don't see why it should do (at least not in general) for continous random variables. What happens when the densities exceed 1 for instance.